LLM to convert binary to decimal
So, I'm a complete beginner on how to use any LLMs, given below is the code which I was using on my jupyter notebook to run a prompt to convert binary to decimal. However I was getting completely incorrect responses on Llama 3.
!pip install -r requirements.txt
import json
import torch
from transformers import (AutoTokenizer,
                          AutoModelForCausalLM,
                          BitsAndBytesConfig,
                          pipeline)
config_data = json.load(open("config.json"))
HF_TOKEN = config_data["HF_TOKEN"]
model_name = "meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B"
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16
)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, use_auth_token=HF_TOKEN)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_name,
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    use_auth_token=HF_TOKEN
)
text_generator = pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
)
def convert_to_decimal(html_input):
    prompt = (f"I'm giving you a input as a binary number"
              f"I need you to convert the binary number to its decimal equivalent. "
              f"Do not give any explanation or add any further text. "
              f"Only provide the transformed output once. "
              f"Don't add any other text except the output. "
              f"For input '101', the output is '5'.\n\n"
              f"{html_input}")
    
    response = text_generator(prompt, max_new_tokens=20, temperature=0.2, return_full_text=False)
    generated_text = response[0]['generated_text'].strip()
    return generated_text
html_input = "1011"
output = convert_to_decimal(html_input)
print(output)

This is my code which I was trying to use, I kept getting the output as
1101 1110 1111..... till it reached the maximum number of tokens. Any help is appreciated about where am I going wrong.

Okay, well your a newbie.
So LLM's are statically continuators of a given text, keep that in mind.
Initially we had LSTM's those managed to predict a next word in a line, and when looped to create sentences they quickly created non sense text. Their consistence at best was 1 alinea. Later large language models got invented, trained on much larger texts, and typical Q & A text combinations.
LLM's manage to see the larger patterns in a given text.
But keep in mind it is still essentially doing pattern continuation.
What your asking it, is to do math, and LLM's dont excel at math.
They can convert dutch to english to italian etc, but math is out of their reach.
Math follows rules and insights that cannot not easily be trained upon.
Most often an LLM can't even tell how much words it's response length is.
So they're a kind of idiot savants, they excel at something but are real poor at other tasks, like abstract calculations.
if you just want a binairy answer in python you be way more efficient doing it directly in python:
def DecimalToBinary(num):
    if num >= 1:
        DecimalToBinary(num // 2)
    print(num % 2, end = '')

Remind that all neural networks are estimators, they're not exact.
They act more akin to fuzie logic (they're the next step).
Perhaps if you want to learn more about neural networks, start with the basics try to solve the kaggle titanic problem: https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/titanic
Or maybe better for a starter  https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/digit-recognizer
There's are also cancer detection contests etc, oh well most people start at kaggle i think.

What about a slightly different task perhaps, maybe like converting the tense of a sentence? How would that work.

It probably works the pattern of words is about the same it knows tense forms. it has some basic understanding of time, it has red training data from so many source texts that it understands how language behaves in past and present, especially english. Some other languages like dutch are not always correct but the dutch (i'm dutch myself) have a bit vague language we get used to all the exception our language has and the none strict rules. It also understands the tone of a question

Well I was actually trying to implement a prompt to convert the tense of a sentence using Llama 3, do you have any hints on how to proceed ?

put this message in the past tense :
I am going to work

try it out on https://groq.com/ it uses lama as well

Well, I want it to be on code as I probably need to input big files later. On code I get all kinds of weird responses, but it somehow works on groq.

maybe start from lmstudio latest version it contains some simple samples.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
